# tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

So, I have 3 windows for my project and I want these 3 windows to have each background image but I don't know how, been figuring this out for many hours now. Here's my code..

```
def Registration():

rootA = Toplevel() # This creates the window, just a blank one.
    rootA.geometry("1366x768")
    rootA.configure(background="black")
    rootA.title('Registation') # This renames the title of said window to 'signup'
    rootA.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

    image3=Image.open('2.gif')
    image4=ImageTk.PhotoImage(image3)
    image3_label=Label(borderwidth=0)
    image3_label.grid(column=0,row=0)

    registrationLabel = Label(rootA, image=image4)
    registrationLabel.place(x=0,y=0)

    fnameEntry= Entry(rootA)
    fnameEntry.place(x=680,y=350,width=200)

def Login():
    global nameEL
    global pwordEL
    global rootA

    rootA = Tk() 
    rootA.geometry("1366x768")
    rootA.configure(background="black")
    rootA.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    rootA.title('Food Delivery') # This makes the window title 'login'

    image2=Image.open('1.gif')
    image1=ImageTk.PhotoImage(image2)
    image2_label=Label(borderwidth=0)
    image2_label.grid(column=0,row=0)

    titleLabel = Label(rootA, image=image1)
    titleLabel.place(x=0,y=0)
```

#  ====== and this part right here is my problem now.

```
def CheckLogin():
    with open(creds) as f:
        data = f.readlines() 
        username = data[0].rstrip()
        password = data[1].rstrip()

    if nameEL.get() == username and pwordEL.get() == password: 
        #r = Tk() # Opens new window
        #r.title('Food Delivery')
        #r.geometry('100x80')
        #r.title("Food Delivery")
        #r.configure(background='pink')

I mean, this part I just label it Tk cos I don't know what to do.

        rootA = Tk() 
        rootA.geometry("1366x768")
        rootA.configure(background="black")
        rootA.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
        rootA.title('Food Delivery') 

        image2=Image.open('4.gif')
        image1=ImageTk.PhotoImage(image2)
        image2_label=Label(borderwidth=0)
        image2_label.grid(column=0,row=0)
```

#  #I have no idea what's the next step or the right code for this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should only ever have a single instance of `Tk` at one time. If you need additional windows, create instances of `Toplevel`.

Each instance of `Tk` is isolated from other instances. Variables, widgets, and images created in one are not visible in the others.

Comment: So, for my third window can I use again the Toplevel?

Comment: I have tried the toplevel again for my 3rd window and it works and there's no error but the image where not visible. How can I display the image? Thanks alot, man!